# How to write to separate files multiple blocks of rows in same Excel spreadsheet (VBA)?

Tags: excel, vba

I am a total VBA illiterate, so I apologize if this seems trivial. I have a simple dataset in an Excel spreadsheet that has 400 rows and 3 columns. It is grouped in smaller sets of 4 rows (1 row of headers and 3 rows of data) and looks like this:

```
Set1    A   B
1      2.5  1.25
2      4.2  3.35
3      6.7  5.75
Set2    A   B
1      3.3  1.65
2      4.1  1.1
3      2.2  7.59
Set3    A   B
1      5.4  2.7
2      3.9  3.35
3      6.7  12.42
```

What I would like to do is

1. write to individual tab-delimited .txt files every block of 4 rows (headers and data)
2. use the name of the group (e.g. Set1) as the output file name (e.g. Set1.txt)

My limited understanding is that I would need to

- loop through the rows through a range of cells
- capture the first cell as a string for the file name
- create/open the output file using that string
- write to file the block of rows
- pursue with the next iteration of the loop

I am sorry that I can't even provide a small piece of code as a starter. I just have a very hard time parsing the various bits of VBA code I could find on this site and others.

Comment: SO is not a freelancer coding site, you will have to google for each to do step you well discribed and mount your solution. If on one of the steps you will encounter a specific problem you are welcom to post it here

Comment: This should help you get started: [AnalystCave: WRITING FILES IN VBA (TXT, XML, CSV, BINARY)](https://analystcave.com/vba-write-file-vba/),[Excel VBA Introduction Part 16 - For Next Loops](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=JyWrLH7monI&index=18&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5),[Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: This key to writing the code would be to step through your loop 4 rows at a time `For r = 1 to LastRow Step 4`.  Not much to it but yeah you should provide some code.

Comment: Thanks TinMan for the literature kickstarters. I got really really confused trying to find the right code pieces bit by bit through googling. In the end, I will need to read these things to get a better grasp of VBA. I never had to use it before, but I have the feeling that I will have to play with it regularly in the future...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range
    Dim r As Long, i As Long
    Dim Fn As String, myPath As String

    myPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    Set rngDB = Range("a1").CurrentRegion

    r = rngDB.Rows.Count

    With rngDB
        For i = 1 To r Step 4
            Set rng = .Range("a" & i).Resize(4, 3)
            Fn = myPath & .Range("a" & i) & ".txt"
            TransToText rng, Fn
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
Sub TransToText(rng As Range, strFile As String)
    Dim vDB, vR() As String, vTxt()
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer, n As Long
    Dim objStream

    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

    vDB = rng

    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        n = n + 1
        ReDim vR(1 To UBound(vDB, 2))
        For j = 1 To UBound(vDB, 2)
            vR(j) = vDB(i, j)
        Next j
        ReDim Preserve vTxt(1 To n)
        vTxt(n) = Join(vR, vbTab)
    Next i
    strtxt = Join(vTxt, vbCrLf)
    With objStream
        '.Charset = "utf-8"
        .Open
        .WriteText strtxt
        .SaveToFile strFile, 2
        .Close
    End With
    Set objStream = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks so much! One little detail: it creates an additional empty .txt file when done.

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through column A and find the cells that have the word "Set" in it.

It then inserts a row a row so that all sets are separated with a blank row.

Since the areas are separated with a blank row, they can be set as range areas, so we can loop through each range area, copy it into sheet2, copy sheet 2 and it becomes a new workbook, save that as a text file and close it.

Make sure to change the folder location in the code and to have the last slash ()

The assumption is sheet(2) is blank, it needs to be indexed, because the code will change the sheet name.

```
Sub Select_Set()
    Dim FrstRng As Range
    Dim UnionRng As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim RangeArea As Range
    Dim fLdr As String, fNm As String

    fLdr = "C:\Users\Dave\SkyDrive\Documents\TestTxtFiles\"    'folder location to save text files

    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Set ws = Sheets(2)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With sh
        Set FrstRng = .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

        For Each c In FrstRng.Cells
            If InStr(c, "Set") Then
                If Not UnionRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set UnionRng = Union(UnionRng, c)    'adds to the range
                Else
                    Set UnionRng = c
                End If
            End If
        Next c

        UnionRng.EntireRow.Insert

        For Each RangeArea In .Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Areas
            fNm = RangeArea.Cells(1).Value
            RangeArea.Resize(, 3).Copy ws.Cells(1, 1)
            ws.Name = fNm
            ws.Copy
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fLdr & fNm & ".txt", xlUnicodeText
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Next RangeArea

    End With

End Sub
```

You can remove the blanks rows

```
Sub reset()
    Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. The code runs into an error:  "Application-defined or object-defined error." I can see that the blank rows have been inserted at the right location in the sheet (first one), but nothing has been copied in the second sheet and no file has been created. If I run it from a blank sheet, and run it line by line, the error happens after the UnionRng.EntireRow.Insert line and says: Object variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: Running the code from a blank sheet, the code would not find any cells that contained "Set". Codes I submit as answers are tested, I set up the workbook like the example you provided.

Comment: My plan was to find the "Set" rows in case there was a time the number of rows changed.